# How to add Images into a Kivy StackLayout?

Tags: android, python, mobile, kivy

I'm trying to put some images into a StackLayout in Kivy, but it is not going on well.

When I put simple Buttons or Labels, the StackLayout adds the widgets like a stack.

But when I add a Label with canvas inside: it didn't work fine.

I'm using a on_press() event to do this. My on_press() function does it:

```
    # The Label works fine without any widget inside it
    lb = Label(text='Hi', size_hint=(1., .1))

    # It just adds only one image
    """with lb.canvas:
        Color(1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle(size=lb.size, pos=lb.pos,
            source='images/parking_free.png')
    """

    lb = Label(text='Hi', size_hint=(1., .1))
    self.ids.my_stack_layout.add_widget(lb)
```

**Ignore the Button in the images, please! I'm using it in my .kv for test.**

**It works fine: [When I use a simple Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmFMs.jpg)**

**It doesn't work: [When I use canvas inside a Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9fPA.jpg)**

Comment: Did you try, what happens if you give the canvas a defined size? Since now you are using `size_hint` for the Label and `size` for the canvas.

Comment: I tried it, but the image is put in other place and seems like they are put over another.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I used the Image Widget and size_hint as the same of the Label and it worked.
img = Image(source='images/parking_free.png', size_hint=(1, .1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't use the Image Widget instead of the Label Widget?

Comment: I tried it, but the image is put outside of the StackLayout.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I used the Image Widget and size_hint as the same of the Label and it worked.
img = Image(source='images/parking_free.png', size_hint=(1, .1))